# Cómo pasar parametros tipo <input type="file" /> al servidor de forma dinámica?

Tags: html, c#, archivo, input

Tengo estas dos etiquetas:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="campo1">
<input type="file" name="files" id="campo2">
```

Y en el servidor recibo los archivos de la siguiente forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Formulario(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
   
}
```

Esto me funciona correctamente. El problema es que quiero saber a qué input le pertenece cada archivo. Los inputs se crean de forma dinámica, es decir pueder ser 10 input. El problema es que no puedo reconocer a que input pertenece cada archivo.

Hay alguna forma de mandar el "id" al servidor?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que llega al action del controller es una lista de archivos pero no hay conexion entre estos y el `tag html` que lo define, es mas no existe esta conexion para ningun control que tengas en la view

Cuando por ejemplo defines

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="txtnombre" />
<input type="text" name="text1" id="txtapellido" />
```

en el action del controller recibes

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Formulario(ICollection<string> text1)
{
}
```

solo recibes un `string` con el dato del `textbox` pero no sabes de cual se trata
Si creas de forma dinamica `<input>` con el mismo `name` lo recibiras en la misma propiedad

Si quieres diferenciarlo entonces cuando crees dinamicamente los tag `<input type="file">`  vas a tener que ponerle un `name` distinto y asi podras recibierlo en propiedades diferentes cuando se aplique el model binding

[Uploading Multiple Files In ASP.NET MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-multiple-files-in-asp-net-mvc/)